# Angular: NgbTypeahead and onScreen keyboard

Tags: angular

I've implemented some autocomplete with the `NgbTypeahaed` bootstrap lib and it works fine. Now i'm trying to attach onScreen virtual keyboard, but I have no idea how to connect between them since the `NgbTypeahaed` firing the event from input's attribute --> `[ngbTypeahead]="autocomplete_data"` when `autocomplete_data` is the source.

So how can I control or 'mock' the events of real typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'mock' the event triggered by outsource element, I dispatched an event to it:

```
let input = document.getElementsByClassName('searchText')[0];
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```